# Normalization for Chi square test

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference

The formula for the Chi-Square test statistic is the following:

$\chi^2 = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{(O_i - E_i)^2}{E_i}$

where O - is observed data, and E - is expected.

I'm curious why it depends on the absolute values? For example, if we change the units we're measuring we'll get a different statistics. Suppose we're performing a test on apple weights. One of the samples weights 165 gram, and we expect it to be 182 gram, then the part of the formula will be:

$\frac{(165 - 182)^2}{182} \sim 1.58791$

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson's_chi-squared_test

Now suppose we're living in a country where the precision is on the top. We use milligrams  for everything and we get the same results in different units: 165000 milligrams and 182000, respectively. The statistic:

$\frac{(165000 - 182000)^2}{182000} \sim 1587.91$

So our conclusion will be different based on the units we used. Why? What am I missing and why the values are not normalized in the Chi-squared test?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the version of this test that I am familiar with, individual data is *categorical*, not quantitative like your examples. And the expected and observed values should be *frequencies* of some category (a count of how many times it occurs), not some individual's quantitative measurement. The numbers that go in to the $E_i$ and $O_i$ positions are unitless, as they are just counts.

So for example, in a box with mixed fruit, maybe 12 pieces were bananas, but you were expecting 15 to be bananas. You will have the term $$\frac{(12-15)^2}{15}$$ and there is no way to rescale units as you did. Writing $$\frac{(12000-15000)^2}{15000}$$ would correspond to a *very* different scenario. There you would have seen 12000 bananas when you were expecting 15000. And the corresponding $P$ value *should* be a lot smaller, because it *should* be a lot less likely to be off by 3000 out of 15000 than 3 out of 15, when you consider the variance from one piece of fruit to the next on its chances to be a banana. So $\chi^2$ *should* be a lot larger in the latter case.

Comment: Given that we're squaring the difference between two counts, why isn't the normalization factor in the denominator squared as well?

Answer (score 1):

The definition of $\chi^2$ you're using is for comparing *frequencies*, not measurements with units. In the later case, you divide by the square of the error, not the value itself.